# Firefox: open history in a tab

Tags: firefox, bugzilla

I was able to open the history panel in a Firefox tab using the url `chrome://browser/content/history/history-panel.xul` until some time ago. With the new Firefox version, this is no longer possible.

Is there any other way to open the history panel in a tab instead than in the sidebar or in a new window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
chrome://browser/content/places/places.xhtml
```

Or else:

```
chrome://browser/content/places/historySidebar.xhtml
```